# JQ merge object into array based on the same key

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a "base" json like this

```json
{
    "Projects": [
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "FOO",
            "Name": "A new Bitbucket project",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "KEY1",
            "Name": "Name1",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "KEY2",
            "Name": "Name2",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "KEY3",
            "Name": "Name3",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "KEY4",
            "Name": "Name4",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "KEY5",
            "Name": "Name5",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

And i have a loop that generates objects like this

```
{ "Project": [ { "KEY": "FOO", "Name": "A new Bitbucket project", "Permissions": [ { "Groups": [], "Users": [] } ] }, { "Permissions": [ { "group": { "name": "test-group-4" }, "permission": "PROJECT_READ" } ] } ] }
{ "Project": [ { "KEY": "KEY2", "Name": "Name2", "Permissions": [ { "Groups": [], "Users": [] } ] }, { "Permissions": [ { "group": { "name": "test-group-1" }, "permission": "PROJECT_WRITE" } ] } ] }
{ "Project": [ { "KEY": "KEY5", "Name": "Name5", "Permissions": [ { "Groups": [], "Users": [] } ] }, { "Permissions": [ { "group": { "name": "test-group-1" }, "permission": "PROJECT_READ" } ] } ] }
{ "Project": [ { "KEY": "KEY5", "Name": "Name5", "Permissions": [ { "Groups": [], "Users": [] } ] }, { "Permissions": [ { "group": { "name": "test-group-2" }, "permission": "PROJECT_WRITE" } ] } ] }
{ "Project": [ { "KEY": "KEY5", "Name": "Name5", "Permissions": [ { "Groups": [], "Users": [] } ] }, { "Permissions": [ { "group": { "name": "test-group-3" }, "permission": "PROJECT_ADMIN" } ] } ] }
```

My whole bash script looks like this

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

while getopts u:p:b: flag; do
    case "${flag}" in
    u) username=${OPTARG} ;;
    p) password=${OPTARG} ;;
    b) url=${OPTARG} ;;
    esac
done

keys=$(curl -s -u $username:$password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" $url/rest/api/1.0/projects/ | jq -r .values[].key)
projects="{\"Projects\" : []}"

for key in $keys; do

    groups=$(curl -s -u $username:$password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" $url/rest/api/1.0/projects/$key/permissions/groups/ | jq)
    project_name=$(curl -s -u $username:$password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" $url/rest/api/1.0/projects/$key | jq -r .name)
    group_names=$(echo ${groups} | jq -r .values[].group.name)
    group_permissions=$(echo ${groups} | jq -r .values[].permission)
    projects=$(echo "$projects" | jq ".Projects[.Projects| length] |={Project:[{KEY:\"$key\",Name:\"$project_name\",Permissions:[{Groups:[],Users:[]}]}]}")

    for group in $group_names; do

        data=$(echo ${groups} | jq -r --arg GROUP "$group" '.values[] | select(.group.name==$GROUP)')
        updated_project=$(echo "$projects" | jq ".Projects[] | select(.Project[].KEY==\"$key\") | .Project[].Permissions[.Permissions | length].Groups[.Groups | length] |= $data")
        projects=$(echo "$projects" | jq "(.Projects[] | select(.Project[].KEY==\"$key\") | . ) |= $updated_project")

    done
done

echo $projects | jq
```

I need to merge those objects into the first json, based on the same KEY value so that it would look like this

```json
{
    "Projects": [
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "FOO",
            "Name": "A new Bitbucket project",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [
                  {
                    "group": {
                      "name": "test-group-4"
                    },
                    "permission": "PROJECT_READ"
                  }
                ],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "KEY1",
            "Name": "Name1",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "KEY2",
            "Name": "Name2",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [
                  {
                    "group": {
                      "name": "test-group-1"
                    },
                    "permission": "PROJECT_WRITE"
                  }
                ],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "KEY3",
            "Name": "Name3",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "KEY4",
            "Name": "Name4",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "KEY5",
            "Name": "Name5",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [
                  {
                    "group": {
                      "name": "test-group-1"
                    },
                    "permission": "PROJECT_READ"
                  },
                  {
                    "group": {
                      "name": "test-group-2"
                    },
                    "permission": "PROJECT_WRITE"
                  },
                  {
                    "group": {
                      "name": "test-group-3"
                    },
                    "permission": "PROJECT_ADMIN"
                  }
                ],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

But all i got is (for when there are multiple same KEY values):

```json
(...)
      {
        "Project": [
          {
            "KEY": "KEY5",
            "Name": "Name5",
            "Permissions": [
              {
                "Groups": [
                  {
                    "group": {
                      "name": "test-group-3"
                    },
                    "permission": "PROJECT_ADMIN"
                  }
                ],
                "Users": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

So only one (last) object was added instead of all of them being appended :/

When i switch to this in the bash script:

```
updated_project=$(echo "$projects" | jq ".Projects[] | select(.Project[].KEY==\"$key\") | .Project[.Project | length].Permissions[.Permissions | length].Groups[.Groups | length] |= $data")
```

I end up with something like this:

```json
(...)
{
  "Project": [
    {
      "KEY": "KEY5",
      "Name": "Name5",
      "Permissions": [
        {
          "Groups": [],
          "Users": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Permissions": [
        {
          "Groups": [
            {
              "group": {
                "name": "test-group-1"
              },
              "permission": "PROJECT_READ"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Permissions": [
        {
          "Groups": [
            {
              "group": {
                "name": "test-group-2"
              },
              "permission": "PROJECT_WRITE"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Permissions": [
        {
          "Groups": [
            {
              "group": {
                "name": "test-group-3"
              },
              "permission": "PROJECT_ADMIN"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So it is under the same Project but as a new object in a list rather than in proper place :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have figured it out. I have changed the .Groups[] index like that

```
updated_project=$(echo "$projects" | jq ".Projects[] | select(.Project[].KEY==\"$key\") | .Project[].Permissions[].Groups[.Project[].Permissions[].Groups | length] |= $data")
```

And it gave me the proper output.